# How long does the Open Graph actions take to get approved from 'pending'?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, action, facebook-opengraph

My Facebook app has had an action pending for some time now. Does anyone know how long it typically takes to get approved for an Open Graph action? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are currently being approved (the process began whenever Timeline was officially launched) and the rate of approval has been stepped up quite a bit, however I cannot give an exact timescale as I don't know where certain submissions sit in the queue.

Comment: Ahh okay. Good to know! Thanks for the response, Matthew! :)

Comment: Just for public knowledge, if you don't mind letting us in on the process, how does the queue work? Is there a certain step by step process that happens for the submissions? Is there a way to speed ahead by doing something to make it easier for you guys to approve or check, maybe?

Comment: The process is basically just ensuring that the actions and objects meet our existing Platform policies (eg. swear words are unlikely to make it through), make sense and that the aggregations are of a good standard (as such, the team has to test live examples of the apps).

The only way to really speed up the process is to ensure that all these things are top notch when you submit them to the queue, thereby ensuring that you'll be accepted the first time. Otherwise, it's basically just FIFO.

Answer (score 6):

My most recent app uses three Open Graph actions, and the approval process for me went like this:
**Actions submitted for approval:** Day 1, about 1 AM IST (or 12:30 PM in the Bay Area)
**One action approved, two sent back to me with suggestions for grammatical improvements:** Day 1, about 7 or 8 AM IST or 7:30 PM in the Bay Area (I'm not 100% certain of time since I was asleep, but gives general idea)
**Two actions resubmitted with suggestions incorporated:** Day 1, about 3 or 4 PM IST or 2:30 AM in the Bay Area
**One action approved, one sent back to me because of lack of steps to test the app:** Day 2, about 5 or 6 AM IST or 4:30 PM in the Bay Area *(the rejection was funny because both the actions had nearly the exact same steps on how to test, with each just requiring a different button press*)
**One action resubmitted with very minute details on how to test the system:** Day 2, about 2 PM IST or 1:30 AM in the Bay Area)
**One action approved, mission accomplished:** Day 3, about 4 AM IST or 3:30 PM in the Bay Area

---

So, few takeaways from my experience:
 1. It currently takes about one working day, with the working hours being probably that in San Francisco or some other American timezone.
 2. To be on the safe side, pay a lot of attention on your grammar. If possible, get the opinion of someone you know who's got excellent English skills to help you out. They might still suggest something minutely different, but if you want to save a day, getting an expert in may be worth it.
 3. I know the "steps to test it" seem extremely obvious to you, but do yourself a favor and imagine your grandmother (if she isn't much tech-inclined) or any other ultra-noob in your family is going to be the person testing the system. Go into excruciating details if you have to, but make sure you don't leave anything out.
 4. This is pretty obvious, and I'm sure 99.99% of you would do this anyway, but make sure to test the publishing of the actions over and over again. You don't want a bug coming in when they are testing, because that is going to cost you some time.
 5. Don't be nervous about it. From the look of it, they are approving any action, as long as it adds value and doesn't do things any good app shouldn't, i.e., publish actions that user never performed, doesn't look to spam the user's timeline, doesn't have any questionable content (eg: porn).

Comment: Can you please provide me,things that required for approve the actions.? I Have followed their action Doc, But I got an reply that "Your usage instructions are incomplete or difficult to understand. Please write step-by-step instructions so that a user can trigger the action and resubmit.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review"

Comment: By the sound of that they didn't seem to have been able to test it due to a lack of step-by-step instructions. It happens, as I mentioned two of my actions had nearly the same except for different button presses, but one got accepted while they requested for more detailed instructions for the other.

Comment: What I'd suggest is go into excruciating detail about how to test it, even if it seems dumb. Something like 
1. Go to <yoururl>.com 
2. Click on <some option> on the navigation bar on top, 
3. Click on <some article>, 
4. Go to bottom of article, 
5. Type your comment and submit. The action "commented on" an article will now be published. 

It seems obvious while reading it, but imagine your instructing someone who barely knows their way around the web, and how you would instruct them to perform your action.

Comment: Thanks for giving your feedback. Just one more doubt I have, while post comes on newsfeed  like (you and your 2 friends are reading this article with title and description) is it possible to add our custom link in this kind of post?

Comment: Yes you can, the actionUrl that you post is of this form:

`var actionurl="/me/<your_apps_namespace>:<action_performed>?<object>="+encodeURIComponent("<URl_you_want_to_redirect_to>");`

Comment: :Thanks once again, please see my dobut  that just now I have posted.

Comment: please have a look own my quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362446/facebook-application-notifier-in-newsfeed

Answer (score 1):

For one of my most recent applications the actions were approved in 4 days